# How to Maintain the quartz triggers history in data base after firing in java

Tags: quartz-scheduler

i am usign SimpleTriggerBean and CronTriggerBean after executing that triggers i need to  maintain the history of triggers for that i create table name is quartz_fired_triggred. How to store the detail of fired triggers in that particular table.

```
 Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
 JobExecutionContext jobExeContext = new JobExecutionContext(scheduler, firedBundle, job);
```

Comment: @Harus: I wonder have you find any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the property JobDetail.Durable = true - which instructs Quartz not to delete the Job when it becomes an “orphan” (when the Job not longer has a Trigger referencing it).

Please note that the triggers are being deleted.

Reference : http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html